# Replace values from a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, raster

I have two rasters and a data frame
ClimRaster= raster with Mean annual temperature MAT values
Clustraster with Integer values from 0-8 representing some clusters.
Clust= Dataframe with two columns Cluster and MAT

I want to make a new raster where 0 values of "Clustraster"  are replaced by values from the overlapping cells of "ClimRaster" and rest values 1to 8 are replaced by corresponding MAT values from a data frame "Clust".

I have a simple example here

```
library(raster)
#generate dummy raster with MAT values
R1 = matrix(runif(100, -5, 12), # the data elements 
       nrow=10,              # number of rows 
       ncol=10,              # number of columns 
       byrow = TRUE) 
ClimRaster <- raster(R1)
plot(ClimRaster, main="MAT°C")
text(ClimRaster, cex=0.5)


#Generate dummy raster for Clusters (integer values from 0-8)

R2 = matrix(sample(0:8, 9, replace =F), # the data elements 
       nrow=10,              # number of rows 
       ncol=10,              # number of columns 
       byrow = TRUE) 
Clustraster <- raster(R2)
plot(Clustraster, main="Clusters")
text(Clustraster, cex=0.5)

#Dataframe with Cluster MAT

Clust<- data.frame(Cluster=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
               MAT=c(2.5, 3,  4.5, 7, 8.5, 9, 10, 12))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subs` to replace the values in a raster with other values, using a data.frame, and then use `cover` to fill in the NAs in one raster with those from another raster.

Example data

```
library(raster)
R1 <- matrix(runif(100, -5, 12), nrow=10, ncol=10, byrow = TRUE) 
ClimRaster <- raster(R1)

R2 <- matrix(sample(0:8, 9, replace =F), nrow=10, ncol=10, byrow = TRUE) 
Clustraster <- raster(R2)

Clust <- data.frame(Cluster=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
               MAT=c(2.5, 3,  4.5, 7, 8.5, 9, 10, 12))
```

Solution

```
s <- subs(Clustraster, Clust)
m <- cover(s, ClimRaster)
```

And with `terra`, you could do it like this:

```
library(terra)
climr <- rast(ClimRaster)
clusr <- rast(Clustraster)
x <- classify(clusr, Clust, othersNA=TRUE)
y <- cover(x, cr)
```